# JAR File Fails - Maven & Hibernate Project

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jar, classnotfoundexception

I have an app that do simple CRUDs ops (Create, read, update, delete with MySQL).
This app is with maven & hibernate. Everything is fine when I debug and execute the app into the IDE (eclipse).

But I need to create a jar of this app, I tried and when I execute the new .jar file looks that everything is ok.

The real problem is when I execute any action for example insert a new record. I fill the textfields and click into the button to save... but DON'T DO NOTHING!

The app only display the GUI but don't do nothing, don't save, don't update don't delete.

What is wrong? exist any special guide to create a .jar file with hibernate?
What should do?

---------------Update-------------

Well I did many thing I created the .jar file with the shell and looks ok I create the manifest and is ok but is the same problem when I launch the .jar from shell show me this:

> Could not initialize the database.  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Looks like the jar cannot found the classpath to mysqulconnector.jar... but is weird because I declare it in the manifest "Class-Path: connector.jar" I dont know how do it.

What should do "attach" or declare the jar to connect to db?

Comment: Can you see the error logs?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use **maven-assembly-plugin** to create a fat jar in order to provide all required libraries to your client application.